# Pushing to multiple github repo at once

Tags: github, push

Is there any easy method to push\upload a file to multiple github repositories at once?
without need to first clone them to local machine. kinda script or cli\gui tool?

I searched across Google, but seems nobody asked\wanted the same thing..

What i trying to achieve is to upload a new renovate.json config to all my repositories under one github account (some of them public, some private, more than 60 repos at all)

Answer (score 0):

What you request is an error prone method. For example, How do you expect the tooling to resolve merge conflicts when they occur in multiple repositories?.

If this file is indeed a shared component. I would recommend to use [submodules](https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255).